# How to format date in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime-format

I am trying to add time in my code below.
Is it possible to display the time in a new line? I am going to display it in a table row.

```js
document.getElementById("date").value = new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10);
```

```html
<label>Arr_date:</label>
<input type="date" id="date" name="Arr_date">
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you please elaborate more on this. My understanding is that you are looking for something like this.

Tuesday

---

12

---

March

---

9999

If you are talking about having a new line between the 2 elements, then I suggest you use a 
 tag

```html
<label>Arr_date:</label>
<br />
<input type="date" id="date" name="Arr_date">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **toTimeString()**:

```
new Date().toTimeString()
```

outputs something like this:

02:35:00 GMT+0200 (...)

We need **hours** and **minutes** (first **five** signs *02:35* -> slice(0,5)):

```
new Date().toTimeString().slice(0,5);
```

HTML:

```
<label>Arr_time:</label>
<input type="time" id="time" name="Arr_date"/>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("time").value = new Date().toTimeString().slice(0,5);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w6dw8urp/

And the dates in a **table**:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Arr_date:</label></td>
        <td><input type="date" id="date" name="Arr_date"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Arr_time:</label></td>
        <td><input type="time" id="time" name="Arr_time"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w6dw8urp/1/

Comment: I want the date and the time to be displayed in the same field and if it's possible in a new line, otherwise side by side. So i think that there will be only one input and one id.

Comment: It is NOT possible to "divide" one input tag in two different rows. If you want to have the date and the time in one line with one input tag you can do this: http://jsfiddle.net/w6dw8urp/3/ .
By the way, my solution is a nice and clean solution! And if it was helpful, please upvote. Thanks!